# Ordering a list by currency value

Tags: c#, linq

I have been trying to think of a clever way to order my list in Linq without much success.

I have a class

```
public class SafeFloatDenomination
{
    public string Denomination { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

I fill this class from the database, and should have a List.
What I would then like to do is to order the list in the following way by denomination:

> **[£50, 50p, £20, 20p, £10, 10p, £5, 5p, £2, 2p, £1, 1p]**

I have been wracking my brains and the only method I have so far managed to get working is the rather uninspiring one of fetching the value I want in turn and adding it to a new list

```
  var l = this._bankingManager.GetSafeFloatCash().OrderByDescending(x => x.Denomination);

        List<SafeFloatDenomination> orderedDenoms = new List<SafeFloatDenomination>();
        SafeFloatDenomination itemToAdd = null;

        itemToAdd = l.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Denomination=="£50");
        if ( itemToAdd!=null)
        {
            orderedDenoms.Add(itemToAdd);
        }

        itemToAdd = l.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Denomination == "50p");
        if (itemToAdd != null)
        {
            orderedDenoms.Add(itemToAdd);
        }

        itemToAdd = l.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Denomination == "£20");
        if (itemToAdd != null)
        {
            orderedDenoms.Add(itemToAdd);
        }

        itemToAdd = l.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Denomination == "20p");
        if (itemToAdd != null)
        {
            orderedDenoms.Add(itemToAdd);
        }
```

What I would prefer to do is strip the £/p and order desc, but this could also just as easily be Euro/c or $/c

I think the best way to start is by creating separate lists of the £ and p, but it's not simple to then pick the matching values from each list:

```
        var poundList = l.Where(x => x.Denomination.Substring(0,1) == "£");
        var penceList = l.Where(x => x.Denomination.Substring(0,1) != "£");
// then add into a new list
```

Comment: Post sample input and sample ouput, I am not sure what you want to do.

Comment: So you have the `decimal Value`, why can't you use that?

Comment: Value is how much of the currency you have

Comment: So `Value` is `10` for `10p` and also `10` for `£10`?

Comment: A more elegant solution for those interested is `MoneyBag`.  Here's one example: https://github.com/bkleinen/Programming-Examples/blob/master/TDD/money/MoneyBag.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(\d+)");

list.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(r.Match(x.Denomination).Groups[1].Value))
    .ThenBy(x => x.Denomination);
```

Comment: Sorry, no value is unrelated to the unit, it is actually the total value of the currency, so for 100 x 10p it would be 10, for 5 x 10p it would be 0.5. The model could obviously use a bit of work

Comment: Ok, added way of extracting the number from the `Denomination`  string first. Tested, works.

Comment: OK cheers, I think this has given me enough clues to sort it out

Comment: @krillgar I already asked, and that `Value` is not what you and I thought it was. See their first comment and my original version.

Comment: Then with that in mind including the first comment, the question suffers dramatically to the point of being incomplete.